# Compile time check if all array members were initialized

Tags: c

Let's say I declare a fixed size array and initialize it's members. Is there a way to check at compile time, if all members were initialized, so that I can avoid bugs because of unitialized values? Here's an example I'm working on:

```
enum image_format {
    IMAGE_FORMAT_UBI = 0,
    IMAGE_FORMAT_BOOT,
    IMAGE_FORMAT_RAW,
    _IMAGE_FORMAT_LAST
};

#define IMAGE_FORMAT_COUNT (_IMAGE_FORMAT_LAST - IMAGE_FORMAT_UBI)

static int image_format_validator_ubi(const char *filename);
static int image_format_validator_boot(const char *filename);

typedef int (*image_format_validator)(const char *filename);

static image_format_validator image_format_validators[IMAGE_FORMAT_COUNT] = {
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_UBI]  = &image_format_validator_ubi,
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_BOOT] = &image_format_validator_boot,
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_RAW]  = NULL
};
```

In this case, I'd like to check that `IMAGE_FORMAT_COUNT` amount of elements were initialized inside the `image_format_validators` array.

Comment: Note that if you have an automatic array without an initializer, or a dynamically allocated array allocated with `malloc()`, or a variable length array (necessarily without an initializer — you can't initialize a VLA), then the contents of the array are indeterminate (but you can be sure that every element was not intialized).  Your code shows static arrays; those are always fully initialized (either explicitly or with the default — zero — initializer).  Arrays allocated with `calloc()` are initialized with all bytes zero.  Extra memory allocated with `realloc()` is not initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to check at compile time, if all members were initialized (?)

There is no partial initialization in C it is all or nothing.  Elements not explicitly initialized will get initialized with a default value.

---

To  help detect if `image_format_validators[]` is the expected size, one approach uses a `_Static_assert(constant-expression , string-literal)`.  If the *constant-expression* is unequal to 0, all is well.  Else "the implementation shall produce a diagnostic message that includes the text of the string literal"  C11 §6.7.10 3

```
enum image_format {
    IMAGE_FORMAT_UBI = 0,
    IMAGE_FORMAT_BOOT,
    IMAGE_FORMAT_RAW,
    IMAGE_FORMAT_N
};

//                                                    v--- empty
static image_format_validator image_format_validators[ ] = {
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_UBI]  = &image_format_validator_ubi,
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_BOOT] = &image_format_validator_boot,
    [IMAGE_FORMAT_RAW]  = NULL
};

#define IFV_N (sizeof image_format_validators/sizeof image_format_validators[0])
_Static_assert(IFV_N == IMAGE_FORMAT_N, "Unexpected size");
```

The above can still get fooled, but does work well to insure a sequential enumerated type mapped to an array has the expected N array elements.

---

If not using C11, see the compile time check alternative: [C_ASSERT(expr)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15270577/2410359).