# Is there a way around using sizeof in a preprocessing conditional?

Tags: c, sizeof, preprocessor-directive

I'm currently updating some code and I ran into a spot where the code makes an assumption about the size of a `time_t` variable being the same as a `signed long`. This code works on our previous platform (so apparently on the Coldfire that was true) but we're moving to a new platform.

Now I know that we should not be making assumptions about the size of a `time_t` variable, since that's [not well defined.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/types.h.html) But I *really* don't want to rewrite all the lines of code which work based on this assumption at the moment.

Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
#if sizeof(time_t) != sizeof(LONG)
#error size assertion failed
#endif
```

once and be done with it. I'm aware that `sizeof()` can't be used in a conditional preprocessor like that so it's out of the question.

So I'm wondering, is there any way I can know the number of bytes that a `time_t` will take such that it can be used in a preprocessing conditional?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro and http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html

Comment: [sizeof in define](http://c-faq.com/cpp/ifsizeof.ct.html) from comp.lang.c faq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're after a compile-time failure then just do something like this

```
{
    char s1[+sizeof(time_t) - sizeof(LONG) + 1];
    char s2[-sizeof(time_t) + sizeof(LONG) + 1];
}
```

Which will fail to build if the sizes differ.

You could put that into a macro, but the error would be rather cryptic.

Comment: Works for me, using C11. time_t was sizeof(int) but failed to compile with sizeof( char)

Comment: "*...  the error would be rather cryptic.*" hehe, and so you really should add a good comment.

Comment: @alk It tells you on what line the error occurs, so its just the matter of adding a comment.

Comment: @Armin; I deleted my comment, making yours a little odd.

Comment: Can be simplified to one array: `char s[2*(sizeof(time_t) == sizeof(LONG)) - 1];`. Then you can rename `s` to be something more descriptive for the compile time error.

Comment: @jxh - that's very nice; especially when renaming s; and with some tricker, OP gets their macro.