# Get number of bits in size_t at compile time

Tags: c, macros, c99

I am trying to get the number of *value* bits in `size_t` to be used in the preprocessor directives. Perhaps there is a macro for this? In essence, I would like to achieve something akin to this code where `SIZE_T_BITS` is a hypothetical macro for the sake of demonstration.

```
#if SIZE_T_BITS == 32
    // code for 32 bit size_t
#elif SIZE_T_BITS == 64
    // code for 64 bit size_t
#else
    // code for other bit sizes of size_t
#endif
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `sizeof` cannot be understood by preprocessor.

Comment: I think the only way is to define such macro for each architecture separately.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro. Some clever stuff may answer.

Comment: `size_t` is defined conditionally, so you have to follow the same conditions for your macro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use "sizeof" in a preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre This is not a duplicate, I want to conditionally handle for different bit sizes of `size_t` but that question is about causing a compile error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size_t` is some unsigned type.  Compare the max value to common candidates. The max value is certainly some 2<sup>SIZE_T_BITS</sup> - 1. The smallest `SIZE_MAX` may be is `0xFFFF`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#if (SIZE_MAX == 0xFFFF)
  #define SIZE_T_BITS 16
#elif (SIZE_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFF)
  #define SIZE_T_BITS 32
#elif (SIZE_MAX == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)
  #define SIZE_T_BITS 64
#else
  #error TBD code SIZE_T_BITS
#endif
```

---

Although `size_t` may have paddings bits (this is rare), the about method reflects  the number of *value* bits in `size_t`.  This could differ from the *total* bits.

---

Note: `SIZE_MAX` is defined such that

> Each instance of these macros shall be replaced by a constant expression suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives, and this expression shall have the same type as would an expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer promotions.  C11 §7.20.3 2

Comment: My only concern is that what if `SIZE_MAX` is defined like `((unsigned int) 0xFFFFFFFF)` with a cast, then it would not compile

Comment: @everyone the preprocessor understands integers, this will be fine.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you that clears up my misunderstanding

Comment: @everyone Answer amended to address your [concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47964313/get-number-of-bits-in-size-t-at-compile-time/47964398#comment82898461_47964398)

Comment: Wait, is it actually guaranteed that `SIZE_MAX` is one less than a power of two? I thought it was, but I also thought it couldn't have padding.

Comment: @DanielH All _unsigned_ types only have value bit and padding bits.  There is no reserved value bit pattern - ergo - SIZE_MAX is a p2m1.  `SIZE_MAX` is the max of the _type_.  Not the max size an object may have - that may be less.  `unsigned char` never has padding.  Padding is so rarely used these days.

Answer (score -1):

This will work for GCC, CLang and MSVC:

```
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_IA64) || defined(__IA64__) || defined(_M_X64)
  #define SIZE_T_BITS 64
#else 
  #define SIZE_T_BITS 32
```