# How to define a variable whose type depends on whether the size of a pointer equals a specific value

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, constexpr

I know that C/C++ preprocessor doesn't know `sizeof`, but I'd like to define a variable in some way similar to this:

```
#if sizeof(char*) == 8
uint64_t a;
#else
uint32_t a;
#endif
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not use a `size_t`?

Comment: @Botje Not guaranteed to be correct; for the specific issue, [`uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) would be better.  But for the *general* question, the answer is template metaprogramming or C++20 concepts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use "sizeof" in a preprocessor macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079243/how-can-i-use-sizeof-in-a-preprocessor-macro)

Comment: gcc and clang will predefine the macro `__SIZEOF_POINTER__`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) like this:

```
std::conditional_t<sizeof(char*) == 8, 
                   uint64_t, 
                   uint32_t> a;
```

Comment: Or `std::conditional<sizeof(char*) == 8, uint64_t, uint32_t>::type a;` if using C++11 but not C++14.