# Barr C coding standard 2018 bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: c, standards

I paste a rule from Michael Barr Coding style book down below.

I found two "mistakes" on sentence: `#if ((8 != sizeof(timer_reg_t))`

1. Michael is using a `sizeof()`, executed at compilation time, on a preprocessor instruction, so far I know it won't ever works, indeed I got the message:

> error: missing binary operator before token "("

Am I missing something?

2. The second issue is a missing')'; I think it is only a mistyping error.

The complete rule is here:

5.5 Structures and Unions
Rules:
a. Appropriate care shall be taken to prevent the compiler from
inserting padding bytes within struct or union types used to
communicate to or from a peripheral or over a bus or network to
another processor.
b. Appropriate care shall be taken to prevent the compiler from
altering the intended order of the bits within bit-fields.
Example:

```
typedef struct
{
uint16_t count; // offset 0
uint16_t max_count; // offset 2
uint16_t _unused; // offset 4
uint16_t enable : 2; // offset 6 bits 15-14
uint16_t b_interrupt : 1; // offset 6 bit 13
uint16_t _unused1 : 7; // offset 6 bits 12-6
uint16_t b_complete : 1; // offset 6 bit 5
uint16_t _unused2 : 4; // offset 6 bits 4-1
uint16_t b_periodic : 1; // offset 6 bit 0
} timer_reg_t;
// Preprocessor check of timer register layout byte count.
#if ((8 != sizeof(timer_reg_t))
# error “timer_reg_t struct size incorrect (expected 8 bytes)”
#endif
```

Comment: `#if (( ())` is not balanced.

Comment: sizeof is interpreted by the compiler not the preprocessor, you can not check it like in preprocessor step. and as others mentioned you paranthesis are not balanced too

Comment: Looks like C23's `static_assert(sizeof(timer_reg_t) == 8, "timer_reg_t struct size incorrect (expected 8 bytes)");` would come in handy.

Comment: static_assert is from c11, why you mention 23? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert

Comment: @amirhm No, `_Static_assert` is from C11. `static_assert` is from C23. (You're looking at the C++ page). You could use `static_assert` in C11 too, but via a macro in `assert.h`.

Comment: Dear, I know brackets must be balanced, I just copy and paste like in the paper, anyway solving this issues main the problem persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot evaluate the sizeof inside the preprocessor. It is evaluated by the compiler. You can simply check like this and should be fine as 8.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
uint16_t count; // offset 0
uint16_t max_count; // offset 2
uint16_t _unused; // offset 4
uint16_t enable : 2; // offset 6 bits 15-14
uint16_t b_interrupt : 1; // offset 6 bit 13
uint16_t _unused1 : 7; // offset 6 bits 12-6
uint16_t b_complete : 1; // offset 6 bit 5
uint16_t _unused2 : 4; // offset 6 bits 4-1
uint16_t b_periodic : 1; // offset 6 bit 0
} timer_reg_t;


int main(){
    printf("%d \n", sizeof(timer_reg_t));
    return 0;
}
```

It will print 8.

If you want to see the compile time verification, you can use a `static_assert` (from `<assert.h>`) as well:

```
static_assert(sizeof(timer_reg_t) == 8, "sizeof(timer_reg_t) != 8");
```

Comment: Note that you'd need `#include <assert.h>` to use `static_assert` in C18 while `_Static_assert` does not require including any headers.

Comment: `%d` is the wrong specifier to print a value of type `size_t`. Use `%zu` instead.

Comment: Thank you , your approach is a good one, but I am still wondering how an experienced programmer like Michael Barr could have published that sentence. I am wondering if there is something else I am missing

Comment: It's a bug, @DanielHSagarra — an oversight which shows that the code shown in the final version of the book was not proofread by a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on both counts. The line you quoted from the book [*Embedded C Coding Standard* by Michael Barr](https://barrgroup.com/sites/default/files/barr_c_coding_standard_2018.pdf) ] has exactly the problems that you have identified.

Your first concern for the line `#if ((8 != sizeof(timer_reg_t))` *(maintaining original line which is missing a closing parenthesis)* is a serious one. Just as you indicated, the sizeof would be evaluated at compile time, i.e. post pre-processing time. Not only is the value not available then, pre-processor directives have already been processed and are gone at the time sizeof could be given a value. In fact, as long as neither sizeof or timer_reg_t have not been #define'd as symbolic constants, the preprocessor will see each of them as 0, effectively giving you `#if ((8 != 0(0))` which is neither functional nor resembles the actual intent.

The answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079243/631266) as well as amirhm's answer here show ways that the goal of Michael Barr in that section of his book can be achieved.

Your second concern, that of a missing ')', is also valid. I would classify it as a minor typo that would need to be fixed, but not of great consequence.