# How can I do short string optimization at compile time?

Tags: c, string, unions, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I have a basic string structure:

```
typedef struct String {
    size_t size;
    union {
        char *ptr, buf[sizeof(char *)];
    };
} String;
```

The idea is to be able to extract a `char *` from a `String` like so:

```
extern String string;
char *str = string.size >= sizeof(char *) ? string.ptr : string.buf;
```

I have a problem. What if I have a `const` `static`/global `String` struct that has to be initialized at compile time? What if I do not want to just hardcode the assumption that `char *` is of a given size?

```
static const String string = {
    sizeof(CONSTANT_STRING)-1,
#if sizeof(CONSTANT_STRING) > sizeof(char *)
    .name
#else
    .buf
#endif
        = CONSTANT_STRING
```

But as we know [`sizeof()` happens after preprocess time so cannot be used in an `#if`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4079243/16217248).

How can I conditionally assign either one member of my string or another to a given value at compile time so the resulting expression is a compile time constant?

Answer (score 2):

### Disclaimer: This answer [requires C23 to work reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77299642/16217248)

In order for the compound literals to be **guarinteed** compile-time constants they have to be specified as `constexpr` which is a C23-specific feature. Otherwise without `constexpr` this may or may not work depending on the compiler and its interpretation of the standard.

---

This could be done but I had to redesign the `String` structure. Instead of having an unnamed nested union, I could have a named union member and conditionally initialize it to different compound literals using the `?:` operator:

```
typedef union Data {
    char *ptr, buf[sizeof(char *)];
} Data;
typedef struct String {
    size_t size;
    Data data;
} String;
#define CONSTANT_STRING "Hello"
static constexpr String string = {
    .size = sizeof(CONSTANT_STRING)-1,
    .data = sizeof(CONSTANT_STRING) > sizeof(char *)
        ? (constexpr Data){.ptr = CONSTANT_STRING}
        : (constexpr Data){.buf = CONSTANT_STRING}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add that there's more room than you're actually using in the `struct`, as a numeral value between 1-8 doesn't need a `size_t` type...

The following incomplete example would add room for 7 more bytes to your small string optimization when used on a 64 bit system:

```c
typedef struct my_string_s {
   unsigned char len[sizeof(size_t)];
   char * ptr;
} my_string_s;
```

Here's an example for "the wild".

The facil.io C STL String module has better optimizations, but this is [from the CLI module](https://github.com/facil-io/cstl/blob/28656b45af8fad2dc0fc2336dbd7e2e2de6c07a1/fio-stl/005%20cli.h#L206-L264) and it shows this approach at work. It's designed for 64 bit systems and might add an extra 4 byte overhead on 32 bit systems (but these 4 bytes will be used by short strings):

```c
/* Note: requires some macros and includes from the facil.io C STL core header */

/** string container */
typedef struct {
  uint8_t em;     /* embedded? const? how long? */
  uint8_t pad[3]; /* padding - embedded buffer starts here */
  uint32_t len;   /* if not embedded, otherwise see `em` */
  char *str;      /* if not embedded, otherwise see `pad` */
} fio_cli_str_s;

/* cli string free / destroy by context */
FIO_SFUNC void fio_cli_str_destroy(fio_cli_str_s *s) {
  if (!s || s->em || !s->str)
    return;
  FIO_LEAK_COUNTER_ON_FREE(fio_cli_str);
  FIO_MEM_FREE_(s->str, s->len);
  *s = (fio_cli_str_s){0};
}

/* cli string info */
FIO_IFUNC fio_buf_info_s fio_cli_str_buf(fio_cli_str_s *s) {
  fio_buf_info_s r = {0};
  if (s && (s->em || s->len))
    r = ((s->em) & 127) ? (FIO_BUF_INFO2((char *)s->pad, (size_t)s->em))
                        : (FIO_BUF_INFO2(s->str, (size_t)s->len));
  return r;
}

/* cli string copy */
FIO_SFUNC fio_cli_str_s fio_cli_str_copy(fio_buf_info_s s) {
  fio_cli_str_s r = {0};
  if (s.len < sizeof(r) - 2) {
    r.em = s.len;
    FIO_MEMCPY(r.pad, s.buf, s.len);
    return r;
  }
  r.len = (uint32_t)s.len;
  r.str = (char *)FIO_MEM_REALLOC_(NULL, 0, s.len + 1, 0);
  FIO_ASSERT_ALLOC(r.str);
  FIO_LEAK_COUNTER_ON_ALLOC(fio_cli_str);
  FIO_MEMCPY(r.str, s.buf, s.len);
  r.str[r.len] = 0;
  return r;
}

/* cli string tmp copy */
FIO_SFUNC fio_cli_str_s fio_cli_str(fio_buf_info_s s) {
  fio_cli_str_s r = {0};
  if (s.len < sizeof(r) - 2) {
    r.em = s.len;
    FIO_MEMCPY(r.pad, s.buf, s.len);
    return r;
  }
  r.em = 128; /* mark as const, memory shouldn't be freed */
  r.len = (uint32_t)s.len;
  r.str = s.buf;
  return r;
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure how that would work. The `size_t` stores any value between `0` and `SIZE_MAX`, but if the value happens to be less than `sizeof(char *)` then the program looks interprets the `union` as an embedded string and otherwise as a pointer to somewhere else. The only way I could think of is if one of the `size_t` bits is used as a flag.

Comment: It would work by making the maximum supported length of the string that much smaller. For example, on 32 bit machines, you might have only 24 bits for length, on 64 bits only 56 bits... this allows you to use a whole `char` (8 bits) for flags and length data. You probably only need 5 bits: 1 for `const` and 4 for embedded length... but the 3 extra bits might not be worth the extra code.

Comment: FYI: 24 bits would sill hold a 16Mb String, which is probably more than you need for a compile time constant.