# Why can GCC not handle compile-time evaluation of compound literal in a ternary with sizeof as a condition inside a struct initializer?

Tags: c, gcc, conditional-operator, compile-time, compound-literals

The following code:

```
struct Int {
    int i;
};
const struct Int i = {sizeof(int) ? (int){1} : 0};
```

Results in:

> initializer element is not constant

[(Live demo GCC)](https://godbolt.org/z/Yz431n6d6)

Even though those statements are at file scope and thus compound literals should be considered constants.

However, if:

- I use [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/qKaeod17W) instead; OR
- I replace the `sizeof(int)` with a 0; OR
- I replace the `(int){1}` with a 1; OR
- The expression is used to initialize an `int` directly instead of an `int` structure member like so: `int i = sizeof(int) ? (int){1} : 0;`

The code will compile just fine.

This raises a few questions:

- Does standard C permit the use of `sizeof()` statements being used with ternaries to initialize one global structure variable member to one of 2 values, at least one of which is a compound literal, all at compile time?
- Why does GCC raise an error if all 3 of the above requirements are met, but if only any 2 or 1 are met, the code compiles fine?

Comment: `(int){1}` looks strange to me, but then, C has some strange quirks..

Comment: With `(int){1}` you tell the compiler to treat the `int` value `1` as an `int` value. It makes no sense. I assume it's only for this questions sake that you have that compound literal? Because if it's in real code somewhere, then just remove it. And if this is just for curiosity, then that's fine but please state so in the question itself. Otherwise please ask about the underlying problem directly instead.

Comment: @user16217248I know, thought this was tagged C++ first, so removed the original comment when I saw it wasn't.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, The incorrect comment is still there, though. `(int){1}` is not a cast. It doesn't tell the compiler to treat the `int` value `1` as an `int`. And `(int){1}` in general does make sense (though not how it's used here).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a 'minimal reproducible example.' In reality, I'd use a compound literal for a struct or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before C23, there was a lot of arguing in gcc and clang bug reports etc, regarding what an integer constant expression consisted of. clang always had the behavior of "anything and its mother is a constant expression", whereas gcc has been more restrictive, until later versions where gcc suddenly flipped behavior even though the standard had not been changed here in ages. All of this was caused by an unhelpful, muddy paragraph in C17 (and earlier standards) 6.6 §10:

> An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.

This is the only part of the chapter 6.6 leaving room for interpretation and allowing code like yours. This means that integer constant expressions have shaky support in both gcc and clang, code using "exotic" forms of constant expressions such as compound literals or `const int x = some_other_const;` is simply non-portable. Most other compilers in the market will give a diagnostic message about non-conforming C.

---

Until C17 an integer constant expression was defined as follows (C17 6.6 §6):

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer
> constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.

In upcoming C23 this changes (C23 N3096 draft 6.6. §8 emphasis mine):

> An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, **named and compound literal constants of integer type**, character constants, ...

Where "named constant" is a new term which among other things covers this:

> declared with storage-class specifier `constexpr` and has an object type,

So C23 will allow `(constexpr int){1}` compound literals and we may also portably do `constexpr int x = 1; const int y=x;`

Comment: It explicitly defines *integer constant expression* as a list of these things and they forgot compound literals until later. But what about `struct` or non-integer types?

Comment: @user16217248 "But what about struct or non-integer types?" Not relevant for this question, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Although this question arose while I was using structs, I asked the question using an integer as an example because I was under the impression that the answer would not be any different whether I used an integer or a struct. Apparently not because the C standard defines *integer constant expression* explicitly instead of just *constant expression* irrespective of type.

Comment: @user16217248 There are various forms of constant expressions and the rules are slightly more lenient during initialization - various other forms of constants are allowed as initializers, although other structs are not. Again, too complex a topic to discuss in comments.