# c preprocessor - fail if compiling after certain date

Tags: c, macros

I would like to make the compilation of some files to fail if attempted after a certain date.  The reason for this: I found a couple of Y2K38 bugs which I don't have time to fix right now, but would like to make a note of them and I think it would be nice if compilation of the module would just fail after, say, 2020.
(I might be insane, but this code is 20 years old I suspect it might survive another 30)

Comment: Isn't the issue more that the program will stop running on 2038, not that it will stop compiling?

Comment: Who cares if you can't compile it after, say, 2020? The issue is whether or not there is compiled version still in production somewhere in 2038. Fix that shit, pronto, and get it deployed.

Comment: Have you considered a #warning?  I've used those before as little to-do's for the future.

Comment: Hopefully your program doesn't involve retirement planning or 30-year mortgages.

Comment: if this was really important I'd fix it immediately; it's mostly non-important reporting stuff that nobody ever looks at.  Do you always fix all the known bugs before shipping a release?  Honestly?

Comment: Not a duplicate IMHO, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c may solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, I can't get any of those static assertions to work for the `__DATE__[9] >= '2'` condition. Hmm...

Comment: What do you do, if the compiler in question has the Y2038 bug, too?

Answer (score 5):

With GCC, you can do something like the following:

```
void __attribute__((error("Whoa. It's the future"))) whoa_the_future();

void check_for_the_future() {
    // "Feb  1 2011"
    const char *now = __DATE__;
    if (now[9] >= '2')
        whoa_the_future();
}
```

The way this works is that the `error` attribute tells GCC to generate
a compile-time error if any calls to that function are left in the
code after all of GCC's constant-folding, dead-code elimination, and
similar passes have run. Since **DATE** is a compile-time constant,
GCC can evaluate the `if` statement at compile time and remove the
call.

At least one downside is that this depends on GCC's optimization
passes, and so it won't work at `gcc -O0`

Honestly, you might be better off just adding a runtime check
somewhere and failing fast.

Comment: By 2100, compilers will automagically fix things like 2038 bugs.

Comment: @aschepler - Hopefully they'll automagically fix 2038 bugs by 2038.

Comment: @nelhage thanks, this is interesting.  Of course, I need this both in VS and gcc :) You are right, runtime check is probably better.

Comment: Try instead something like `const char[1+2*('2'-__DATE__[9])];`

Comment: @R.. - That errors at 2030, which is 10 years later than the OP asked for. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c

Comment: he he he he, great comment aschepler

Answer (score 5):

Instead of dealing with the awkward format of the `__DATE__` macro, why not roll your own?

```
gcc -DTHIS_YEAR=`/bin/date +%Y` yourprogram.c
```

Then your code can use expressions like `#if THIS_YEAR >= 2020`.

Comment: oh, I like this... sort of.  A little too fragile.  The build system is likely to change in the next 10 years and this will get broken.

Comment: @MK: you can also have an `#if` that generates an `#error` if `THIS_YEAR` isn't defined, which will ensure build system changes maintain this functionality.

Comment: If I encountered that in a build system, I would simply add `-DTHIS_YEAR=2011` to the `CFLAGS`... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a horrible solution:

1. In your project's general-purpose header directory, run the following (Python) script:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python

   months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
             'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

   cutoff = 2020
   #safety = 2025

   for year in range(2011, cutoff):
       for month in months:
           for day in range(1, 32):
               t = open("%s %2d %d" % (month, day, year), "w")
               t.write("\n");
               t.close()

   #for year in range(2011, cutoff):
   #    for month in months:
   #        for day in range(1, 32):
   #            t = open("%s %2d %d" % (month, day, year), "w")
   #            t.write("#error \"Too old\"\n");
   #            t.close()
   ```

   Uncomment the commented-out lines to produce better diagnostic messages.
2. In the files that need to error after the cutoff date, use this:

   ```
   #include __DATE__
   ```

I dare you to use this in production code.

Comment: this is getting out of hand but I guess that's what I asked for :)

Comment: +1 for: (1) making me laugh, and (2) being sane enough to include the first sentence.

Comment: @MK - I found another question on SO that may help you out (in case you didn't see it in the comments for the question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c

Comment: I feel bad for getting 40 reputation for this. I might have to make this Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

`__DATE__` is not the proper thing for such a goal:

> If the date of translation is not
>   available, an implementation-defined
>   valid date shall be supplied.

Any future broken C compiler that still only implements C99 :) and not any of its followers may fix the date to `"Jan  1 1970"` or have it wrap once beyond the fatal date in 2038.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, this is true (and I laugh at the phrase "_still only_ implements C99" - that'll be the day), but in practice no modern compiler's internal date is going to fail before 2038, and since the OP wants a warning well before that date this should work. But +1 for technical correctness.

Comment: No that is not only theoretical. Somebody who will still try to compile a version of code where this ain't fixed at that time is very likely to use a then broken compiler, too. In particular, if the compiler implementor uses the same strategy and the compiler's `__DATE__` wraps (which is legal). So in essence, `__DATE__` is the wrong answer to a wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution that should work with most compilers. It depends a bit on the format of the **DATE** preprocessor directive

```
#define DIGIT(ch) (((ch)<'0'||(ch)>'9') ? 0 : ((ch)-'0'))
#define YEAR (1000*DIGIT(__DATE__[7])+100*DIGIT(__DATE__[8])+10*DIGIT(__DATE__[9])+DIGIT(__DATE__[10]))

#ifdef YEAR-2020>0
#error too old
#endif
```

Comment: Array subscripting does not work at the preprocessor level. Sorry.

Comment: @R I think it does.  I tried his code and YEAR does get the correct value of 2011, but it is not clear how to use it (to me).

Comment: @MK - `YEAR` has the correct value in compilation, but at preprocessing time cannot be used to signal an `#error`

Comment: @Chris yes, I just wasn't parsing what @R said.  Actually, I still don't fully understand what he meant, but yes, looks like this approach is incorrect.

Comment: @steve - Not for me. A) You're using `#ifdef` when you obviously mean `#if`. B) With `#ifdef` for me the error triggers (and I'm not from a time traveller.) C) `#if` directives cannot process strings, even string subscripts.

Comment: @Chris: I don't mean #if, I mean #ifdef as this will either evaluate to 1 or 0

Comment: @steve - That's not the proper syntax for `#ifdef`, and when I copy-and-paste your code through my compiler (`gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5470) (Aspen 5470.3)`) I get `<stdin>:5:2: error: #error too old`.

Comment: I get "y.c:6:1: error: token ""Feb  2 2011"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions"
on gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)