# C typecasting for structure pointers

Tags: c, struct, casting

Confused in some example with realization of trivial intrusive container in C.
I have structures:

```
struct List {
    struct Link* first;
    struct Link* last;
};
```

And Link for become the nodes of list:

```
struct Link {
    struct Link* pre;
    struct Link* suc;
};
```

Some pseudo Node for storing specified values in List:

```
struct Name {
    struct Link lnk;
    char* n;
};
```

Function for pushing values in List:

```
void push_back(struct List* lst, struct Link* p) {
    assert(lst);
    {
        struct Link* last = lst->last;
        if (last) {
            p->pre = last;          
            last->suc = p;                                      
        }
        else {
            lst->first = p;
            p->pre = 0;
        }
        lst->last = p;
        p->suc = 0;
    }
}
```

And usage of List:

```
int main() {

    int count = 0;
    struct List names;
    struct Link* curr;
    init(&names);

    push_back(&names, (struct Link*)make_name("Norah"));
    push_back(&names, (struct Link*)make_name("Annemarie"));
    push_back(&names, (struct Link*)make_name("Kris"));

    curr = names.first;
    for (; curr != 0; curr = curr->suc) {
        count++;
        printf("element %d: %s\n", count, ((struct Name*)curr)->n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Question is, how typecast is working in this example? when `sizeof(Link)==8` and `sizeof(Name)==12`
The pointer `curr` pointing to allocated memory for type `Name`, this structure not have `suc` and `pre` members,just `lnk` object of type `Name` (not pointer), and in code no any primary access for this member.

Comment: The address of a structure is equivalent to the address of its first member. Therefore, if you have a structure `Name` that always has a `Link` as the first member, then the address of that `Name` is also the address of that `Name` ' s `Link` member, and can be utilized accordingly. Just don't do pointer arithmetic with it. The compiler can shove padding, and alignment adjustments at-will between members, but never before the *first* member.

Answer (score 1):

It is relying on the fact that `struct Link` is the first field of the `struct Name`. You can pretend the 12 bytes pointed to by a `struct Name*` is actually an 8 byte `struct Link`, and disregard the remaining 4 bytes. See the following questions:

- [Struct pointer compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702713/struct-pointer-compatibility)
- [Is casting a struct T* to a struct C* undefined behavior, if T's first field is a C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510954/is-casting-a-struct-t-to-a-struct-c-undefined-behavior-if-ts-first-field-is)
- [Does accessing the first field of a struct via a C cast violate strict aliasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747010/does-accessing-the-first-field-of-a-struct-via-a-c-cast-violate-strict-aliasing)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! Im lost from mind that `struct Link` have two first members which each one 4 bytes. When `struct Name` is come to `push_back()` via argument, the function is operate with him like a `struct Link`.Cuz `struct Name` have 8 byte member in a head, functions just placing data about `suc` and `pre` members in this 8 bytes. I can replace `lnk` member from `Name` to any other with data with size 8 bytes.

Have i nice day!