# How to test bit field size

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

To save space in an embedded C project, I am using bit fields to index some small arrays. Because a bit field size must be a constant, this means defining two interdependant constants with the corresponding possibility for error if one or the other is independantly changed.

I am looking for a way to use the preprocessor to check if the defined bit field size is large enough to contain the array size. This should produce a compile error.

Comment: why don't you just define the bitfield size then just compare when needed. For example `#define BITFIELDSIZE 6` `assert(ARRAYSIZE < (1 << BITFIELDSIZE))`

Comment: What kind of space are you saving by doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a preprocessor constant to define the bitfield size (there may be a way to achieve a compile-time assertion without doing that but it doesn't immediately spring to my mind).

```
#define WIDGET_COUNT_BITS 5
#define WIDGET_MAX ((size_t)(1 << WIDGET_COUNT_BITS - 1))
struct widget_list {
    unsigned count : WIDGET_COUNT_BITS;
};
```

If the array size is defined by a preprocessor constant, you can use the preprocessor to get an error message.

```
#define FROBNICATOR_WIDGET_COUNT 42
#if FROBNICATOR_WIDGET_COUNT > WIDGET_MAX
#error "Too many widgets in the frobnicator module"
#endif
widget_t widgets[FROBNICATOR_WIDGET_COUNT];
```

Otherwise, if you want a compile-time error based on a `sizeof` value, a classic trick to is to build an array type, which most compilers reject if the array size is 0. See [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c/3385694#3385694). [C11 introduces `_Static_assert`](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-static-assertions.html) for that, but compiler support isn't widespread yet.

Comment: Thinking backwards! #define NUM_FROM_BITS(a) (1<<a) #define MAX_NUMBER 16 #define MAX_NUMBER_BITS 4 #if NUM_FROM_BITS(MAX_NUMBER_BITS) < MAX_NUMBER #error "Not enough bits in MAX_NUMBER_BITS" #endif Many thanks.