# Check some compile-time definitions at compile time with older C++ implementations

Tags: c++, compile-time, static-assert, compile-time-constant, c++builder-6

When working on a large legacy code base, I today suspected a duplicate definition, but the dependency was not obvious to me human since it depended on a lots of compile-time calculations.

```
enum { MAX_ITEMS = 4 }; // defined somewhere in my code universe
enum { ITEMS_MAX = COMPLICATED_CALCULATIONS }; // somewhere else
```

I remembered some cases with analogous `sizeof` questions, when **I let the compiler speak**.

I usually put some ad-hoc formulations like this in the code (in the IDE), then I press [Alt]+[F9]:

```
void check() {
    char bla[MAX_ITEMS == ITEMS_MAX]; // compiler-error shows difference
    // ...but it causes a compiler warning about bla being never used
}
```

...and that's only because my compiler (Borland C++ 5.6.4) lazy evaluates the `typedef` for arrays with non-literal dimension:

```
typedef char bla[0];       // immediate compiler error
typedef char bla[0 != 0];  // obvious, but no compiler error HERE
```

Is there a really easy-to-memorize way for checks like this? <sub>And, please don't blame an old brave compiler ;-)</sub>

Comment: You want a static assert?

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, seems so, I didn't know the term, sorry.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a free software C++11 compiler (recent [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) or recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the tip :) but the code base suffers from *compiler lock-in* :(

Comment: In the following link there are more detailed discussions about implementing one's own static assert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(x) typedef char foo[(x) ? 1 : -1];
```

I actually use the following setup borrowed from Boost, the purpose of this is to give each foo its own line number (otherwise a multiple definition error can happen):

```
#define BOOST_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y )
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN( X, Y ) BOOST_DO_JOIN2(X,Y)
#define BOOST_DO_JOIN2( X, Y ) X##Y
#define STATIC_ASSERT(x) \
    typedef char BOOST_JOIN(violation_on_line_,__LINE__) [(x) ? 1 : -1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try if [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) works on your compiler.