# Prevent Compilation of Code Using Macro in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macros

I am trying to find a way to prevent user from even compiling the code based on value of some user-defined build setting such as `DEBUG=1`. First thing that popped out in my mind is to write a macro something like this;

```
#if DEBUG=1
    #define NS_UNAVAILABLE_IN_PROD NSLog(x);
#else
    #define NS_UNAVAILABLE_IN_PROD
#endif
```

so I am able use it like this;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   NS_UNAVAILABLE_IN_PROD

   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

When I try to compile the code, I get the error:

> Use of undeclared identifier '**x**'

which is expected, but in some cases, depending on the place where I put this check, a local variable **x** may be initialized before that so it passes without any error. Thus, I need a more clever way to inform user that the code can't be compiled because he is in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Careful using `#ifdef DEBUG`. If you have `DEBUG=0`, `#ifdef DEBUG` is still true. You want `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to happen when `DEBUG=1`? Do you want to simply log a fixed message?

Comment: You fixed the code incorrectly. You want `#if DEBUG`. Then put the non-debug code in the `else` part and the debug code in the `if` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question you are looking for `#error`, e.g.:

```
#if DEBUG
#error "Will not compile"
#endif
```

**After Comments**

What I'm suggesting is you do:

```
#if DEBUG
#error "This method only available in production"
#endif
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
   self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

It might be nice if you could define that as a macro itself, but I don't think you can.

You can place that code multiple times into a file.

You can also use `_Static_assert` as in the other question you've linked to:

```
#define DEBUG_ONLY _Static_assert (!DEBUG, "Only available in debug");

DEBUG_ONLY - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

but note you need to put it at the start of the line not at the end.

Comment: The OP seems to want a compilation error at a specific location in the code and probably at multiple locations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c  This is very close to what I want to do but I don't know how to do it in obj-c.

Comment: @ozgurv - I've updated the answer, maybe that will help