# Why do I get "conflicting declaration" error using two and more typedef-based static asserts with gcc and template function?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, static-assert

I have the following code (no, the template is not instantiated anywhere):

```
#define cAssert( expr ) typedef char __C_ASSERT__[( expr )?1:-1]

template<int t>
void f()
{  
   cAssert( t != 0 );
   cAssert( t != 2 );
}
```

which compiles just fine with Visual C++ (when `t` is neither 0 nor 2 of course). Yet gcc (4.9.0 and earlier - you can test them on http://gcc.godbolt.org/) outputs this:

```
In function ‘void f()’:
1 : error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef char __C_ASSERT__ [((t != 2) ? 1 : (-1))]’
#define cAssert( expr ) typedef char __C_ASSERT__[( expr )?1:-1]
```

If I only leave a single `cAssert()` (any of the two) - it compiles fine. The problem is there only when I have both of them.

Why would gcc reject this code and how can I fix this?

Comment: Not an answer, but why not using [`std::static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) instead of rolling your own?

Comment: No idea whether gcc is correct or not, but you should be able to fix the error by adding braces around each `cAssert` expression.

Comment: cygwin in netbeans will produce same error.

Comment: @Praetorian how exactly do you mean to do it? I tried, but failed.

Comment: [Here's](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51671) the bug report. @G.Samaras `{cAssert( t != 0 );}`

Comment: It worked with cygwin too. To state the obvious if with have same values in both asserts with the code of OP, it will still work.

Comment: @Praetorian That would only work at block scope, though. It may be good enough, or it may not be. An alternative is a macro concatenation with `__LINE__` in the typedef name (and trusting the user to place each assertion on a line of its own).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This is very old code that has to be compiled on numerous compilers including ones that don't have `static_assert` with them.

Comment: @sharptooth When googling for this, I found several bug reports regarding MinGW, cygwin, Wine compiler implementations with `__C_ASSERT__`, but nothing up-to-date enough, explaining for GCC 4.9. Sorry :(

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why this does not work.

One and a half fix:

```
#define cAssertbraces( expr ) typedef char __C_ASSERT_BRACES__[( expr )?1:-1]

template<class T>
void cAssert(T v1, T v2) {  {cAssertbraces( v1 != v2 );} }

template<int t>
void f()
{  
    {cAssertbraces( t != 0 );}
    {cAssertbraces( t != 2 );}
    cAssert(t, 0);
    cAssert(t, 2);
}
```

or, use `__LINE__` like this:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(COND,MSG) typedef char static_assertion_##MSG[(!!(COND))*2-1]
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT3(X,L) STATIC_ASSERT(X,static_assertion_at_line_##L)
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT2(X,L) COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT3(X,L)
#define COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT(X)    COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT2(X,__LINE__)

...
COMPILE_TIME_ASSERT( t != 2 );
```

which I took from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c) (nice answers there, should check).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that GCC rejects the code is essentially that, after the macro has been expanded, you have a differing sequence of tokens comprising the declaration of the type. Consider a much easier example:

```
template <unsigned t>
void f()
{  
    using type = int[t + 0];
    using type = int[t    ]; // Adding a +0 here makes GCC compile it fine
}
```

[GCC complains](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23e5dc47d6c97a72). However, this was covered by [**core issue 422**](http://wg21.link/cwg422), where CWG concluded that

> We believe that all these cases should be allowed, and that **errors should be required only when an instance of the template is generated. The current standard wording does not seem to disallow such cases, so no change is required.**

That is, GCC is wrong.