# C no op statement outside functions

Tags: c, preprocessor

I have code containing many lines such as:

```
static_assert(sizeof(my_stuct)==42, "check struct size");
```

and I want to compile on a compiler which has no static_assert implemented. So I want these lines to become no-op. I've tried:

```
#define static_assert(COND, MSG)
```

it works fine but I get a warning with clang compiler:

```
warning: extra ';' outside of a function [-Wextra-semi]
```

Is there a simple no-op C statement to be used outside functions which terminates with a semicolon and which can be used repeatedly?

Comment: would you consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c as a duplicate - even though it asks *how to implement* it?

Comment: `static_assert` is a macro in `assert.h` header for C11 standard implementations. So, you can test for its existence and map it to your own macro if not. Just make sure you include the header, otherwise you could interfere with some custom name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to compile on a compiler which has no static_assert implemented. So I want these lines to become no-op.

Why not combining Lundin's answer (checking whether the current compiler *has* it implemented or not) with an *implementation* of `static_assert` (which is not hard to do)?

Copying the implementation from [PDCLib](https://rootdirectory.ddns.net/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=PDCLib&path=%2Ftrunk%2Finclude%2Fpdclib%2F_PDCLIB_int.h) (which is [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/choose/zero/) licensed):

```
/* with dodgy implementations, you could also #ifndef static_assert */
#if !defined __STDC_VERSION__ || __STDC_VERSION__ < 201112
#define _PDCLIB_cc( x, y )     x ## y
#define _PDCLIB_concat( x, y ) _PDCLIB_cc( x, y )

#define static_assert( e, m ) enum { _PDCLIB_concat( _PDCLIB_assert_, __LINE__ ) = 1 / ( !!(e) ) }
#endif
```

For a given expression `e` and message m, this declares an anonymous enumeration with one member, the name of which is `_PDCLIB_assert_` concatenated with the current source file line (`__LINE__`) (so you can have multiple `static_assert()` per source file). This member is set to `1` divided by `1` if the expression `e` is true, or divided by `0` if the expression is false, which leads to output like this for a failed assert:

```
./path/to/source.c:57:94: warning: division by zero [-Wdiv-by-zero]
 #define static_assert( e, m ) enum { _PDCLIB_concat( _PDCLIB_assert_, __LINE__ ) = 1 / ( !!(e) ) }
                                                                                      ^

./path/to/header.h:571:1: note: in expansion of macro 'static_assert'
 static_assert( false, "test" );
 ^
./path/to/source.c:57:62: error: enumerator value for '_PDCLIB_assert_571' is not an integer constant
...
```

It's not pretty, but it's perfectly C89-compliant, tested, and servicable.

Feel free to rename from `_PDCLIB_*` to anything you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had a C99 implementation of static_assert which, unfortunately, was generating warnings about unused variables.

Comment: `static_assert` exists as a non-standard extension and also as a C++ keyword. So the absence of C11 is no guarantee of the absence of `static_assert`, should we allow portability to non-standard C or C++.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: I'd like to give credit to the guys who helped me forging this implementation, but I cannot remember who they were or where we had the discussion about it, sooo... you're welcome, anyway. ;-)

Comment: As for the assertion itself, it looks similar to the icky one somewhere in the Linux kernel. If I have to use older C, I like to use something like `#define STATIC_ASSERT(expr) {typedef uint8_t STAT_ASSERT[(expr) ? 1 : 0];}` Much more readable.

Comment: @Lundin: Should we check for `#if ( __cplusplus < 201103L ) || ! defined( static_assert )`? Would that hold for non-standard C and C++?

Comment: @Lundin: There is something broken with your alternative implementation (`expected identifier or '(' before '{' token`).

Comment: It will work in C, but what happens if you put `! defined( static_assert )` in a conforming C++ implementation? Won't it moan about using keywords incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not sure if my solution works at file scope (because I never use assert there). Also include stdint.h, though the type `uint8_t` isn't really necessary, could as well use `int`.

Comment: @Lundin: Well, the implementation I provided was intended to be a fully standard-compliant implementation of `static_assert()`, which *needs* to work at file scope. As OP is looking at code already *containing* `static_assert`, quite possibly _at_ file scope, it's IMHO better to give him a compliant solution rather than a pretty one. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179108/discussion-between-devsolar-and-lundin).

Answer (score 2):

My solution so far:

```
#define static_assert(COND, MSG) extern int __static_assert_dummy__
```

works fine but seems ugly to me!

Answer (score 2):

Tested only very quickly, but how about:

```
#define static_assert(COND, MSG) extern int _no_static_assertion
```

or something? Repeating an `extern` should be fine.

Comment: thanks! I arrived at the same solution... (there is an extra #define, however)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a C11 feature, the answer is quite trivial: simply check if the compiler supports C11.

```
#if defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112
  static_assert(sizeof(my_stuct)==42, "check struct size");
#endif
```

The opposite, to make this a no-op in the absence of standard C, and thereby remove the need for the above compiler switches all over the place, is this:

```
#if !defined __STDC_VERSION__ || __STDC_VERSION__ < 201112
  #define static_assert(cond, str) struct dummy_t
#endif
```

Though remember that `static_assert` requires `#include <assert.h>`, unlike the C11 keyword `_Static_assert`.

Comment: Yes, in fact I actually wrote the code like that ("the opposite"). The point is that I get the warning about extra semicolon, which is annoying

Comment: Unfortunately I get a warning: warning: redefinition of typedef 'dummy_t' is a C11 feature [-Wtypedef-redefinition]

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Ah right you can't have several static_assert in same scope with the `typedef` method. Hmm... how about this? `struct dummy_t`. Forward-declaring a struct. You can do this multiple times in the same scope.

Comment: Reason why I want to avoid `extern` is because you might have static analysers etc set to block the use of `extern` anywhere in your code (anti-spaghetti checks). I have that in some projects.

Comment: yes, this is better than the "extern" solution. About my removed comment "avoiding to add symbols to namespace" is only a question to avoid possible (even if unlikely) name clashes.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I can't come up with anything at file scope containing a `;` which is not part of a declaration, so I don't think the namespace clutter can be avoided.