# How people check nan and inf in C89

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, c99, c89

`isnan(), isinf()` was not in the spec until C99, is there anyway to implement such a function in C89?

i could use `if (d * 0 != 0)` to check if d was NaN or Inf, but we always compile our project with option `-Werror=float-equal` which would like to shouting out :`error: no == or != on float point value`

How people check nan and inf in C89 then?

Comment: Try `x > DBL_MAX` for infinity and `x != x` for NAN.

Comment: C99 has been out for 20+ years.  Why the interest  in C89?

Comment: @chux I think your first comment could become a nice answer to an interesting question, with a little explanation. I would not be able to provide a good explanation, so can I ask you to create an answer?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I was professionally confined to C89 until some 5 years ago. It was a question of purpose-oriented qualification and licenses with the used compilers in a slightly unusual environment. Also some worries about code behaviour people relied on. All with a touch of not entirely unreasonable paranoia.

Comment: @Yunnosch Answer posted.  [not entirely unreasonable paranoia](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/just-because-i-m-paranoid-doesn-t-mean-they-re-not-out-to-get-me)

Comment: @Yunnosch the first comment of @chux may not work because of the compile option `-Werror=float-equal`.

Comment: @hukeping Would that interesting comment not be more helpful with the answer by chux and addressed to chux?

Comment: hukeping, If code warns due to `-Werror=float-equal`, simple disable that warning for that section of code. [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3378560/2410359).

Comment: chux,  i think `#pragma directive` would work.

Answer (score 7):

**Since C99**

`isinf(x)` and `isnan(x)` work on the *real-floating* type of `x` and is undefined for other types like `int`.   `isinf(x)` and `isnan(x)` are macros.

`isinf(x)` and `isnan(x)` use the same name for `float, double, long double` and so act like an overloaded function.

**isinf**

For C89 we could use separate functions to test against `_MAX`. Note that C89 does not define `long double`.

A "roll your own" `isinf()` can use the below.

```
#include <float.h>
int isinf_f(float x) { return x < -FLT_MAX || x > FLT_MAX; }
int isinf_d(double x) { return x < -DBL_MAX || x > DBL_MAX; }
```

Note that C does not require that an implementation support *infinity*.  If so, the above are never true.

**isnan**

A "roll your own" for C89 `isnan()` is trickier.  Could be done below as functions or a simply macro.  Functionality  relies on modern Not-a-number behavior where a Nan is never equal to anything, not even itself.  This is *not* specified by C89 but commonly the underlying floating point system follows this.  Otherwise you need a more platform specific approach.

```
/* Note `x` used twice here - so use with caution */
#define my_is_nan(x) ( (x) != (x) )

int isnan_f(float x) { x != x; }
int isnan_d(double x) { x != x; }
```

Note that C does not require that an implementation support *Not-a-number*.  If so, the above are never true.

Given the C89 wild-wild-west era, I would not assume IEEE 754 compliance.  *Infinity* and *NAN* are exactly the fringes of any floating point implementations that lack formal compliance.  Good luck.

---

C allows use of FP  wider math depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` so `1.0f / 7.0f` might use `double`.  This complicates things a bit, yet using a true function does coerce `x` expression into the desired type.

Answer (score 2):

If your system uses the [IEEE 754 Standard](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/) to represent floating point values (as most do), then you can explicitly check for the `NaN` and `inf` values. Single-precision (32-bit) floating-point values have `1` **sign bit** (bit 31), an `8 bit` **exponent** (bits 30-23) and a `23 bit` **mantissa** (bits 22-0), laid out like so (in binary format):

```
SEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

An **infinity** value is denoted with an exponent of all 1s and a mantissa of all 0s (the sign bit distinguishes between negative infinity and positive infinity).

A **NaN** value is denoted by an exponent of all 1s and a non-zero fraction (a *quiet NaN* has the most significant mantissa bit *set*, whilst a *signalling Nan* has this bit clear).

So, by 'casting' the `float` to an unsigned, 32-bit integer, we can explicitly check for these representations (assuming `unsigned int` is a 32-bit type):

```c
int IsInfinite(float test) {
    unsigned int mask = *(unsigned int *)(&test);
    return ( (mask & 0x7F800000) == 0x7F800000 && (mask & 0x007FFFFF) == 0 );
}

int NotANumber(float test) {
    unsigned int mask = *(unsigned int *)(&test);
    return ( (mask & 0x7F800000) == 0x7F800000 && (mask & 0x007FFFFF) != 0 );
}
```

The representation for double-precision values is similar, but with `11` exponent bits (62-52) and `52` mantissa bits (51-0).

Comment: `unsigned int mask = *(unsigned int *)(&test);` violates strict aliasing, [ignores any potential endianness issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness), and assumes all the bits of a `float` fit exactly into an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , do you mean if the  floating-point numbers are represented in big-endian form in our hardware, these two functions will not work properly?

Comment: @hukeping: The method fails when float has a different endian-ness as `int`. That does not happen on real hardware - it breaks basic ideas behind IEEE754, such as sorting numbers by their binary representation.

Answer (score 1):

On review, perhaps another approach for C89.

If we assume comparing a NaN with a finite value is always false (which is the IEEE approach), we could guess that on such systems that do not follow that that the compare is always true (versus sometimes true).  The trick would then be to handle both cases.

With `x` as a non-Nan, `(x >= 0.0) == (x < 0.0)` should always be false as mathematically they are the opposite tests.

With `x` as a NaN, if we are fortunate that such `x` vs. constant compares are always false or always true, the `is_nan()` result is true.

```
// Assuming -Werror=float-equal 
int is_nan(double x) {
  return (x >= 0.0) == (x < 0.0);
}
```

As possible, I would also input a `static_assert()` for a C89 compile.  Given `_Static_assert` does not exist in C89, consider various C89 substitutes as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29016423/2410359).

Answer (score -2):

I would like to try to expose **NaN** by a logical consideration.

If a `float` is **not infinite** (neither greater than `FLT_MAX` nor less than `-FLT_MAX`), it should therefore be less than or equal to `FLT_MAX`. If not, it is **NaN**.

```
int is_inf(float x) { return x < -FLT_MAX || x > FLT_MAX; }
int is_nan(float x) { return !is_inf(x) && !(x <= FLT_MAX); }
```

---

My very first answer and already down voted. So I decided to add an example. Well, it works as expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

static int is_inf(float x) { return x < -FLT_MAX || x > FLT_MAX; }
static int is_nan(float x) { return !is_inf(x) && !(x <= FLT_MAX); }

static void show(float f)
{
  float g = -f;
  printf("% f : %i %i %i %i\n", f, isinf(f), isnan(f), is_inf(f), is_nan(f));
  printf("% f : %i %i %i %i\n", g, isinf(g), isnan(g), is_inf(g), is_nan(g));
}

int main(void)
{
  float inf = FLT_MAX * 2.0f;
  float nan = inf / inf;

  show(inf);
  show(nan);
  show(FLT_MAX);
  show(FLT_MIN);
  show(0.0f);
  show(1234.5678f);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and started under Linux:

```
$ gcc infnan.c
$ ./a.out
 inf : 1 0 1 0
-inf : -1 0 1 0
-nan : 0 1 0 1
 nan : 0 1 0 1
 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 : 0 0 0 0
-340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000 : 0 0 0 0
 0.000000 : 0 0 0 0
-0.000000 : 0 0 0 0
 0.000000 : 0 0 0 0
-0.000000 : 0 0 0 0
 1234.567749 : 0 0 0 0
-1234.567749 : 0 0 0 0
```

---

Complementary solution for the data type `double` with improved return value.

```
static int is_inf(double x) {
  if (x >  DBL_MAX) return  1;
  if (x < -DBL_MAX) return -1;
  return 0;
}
static int is_nan(double x) { return !is_inf(x) && !(x <= DBL_MAX); }
```

---

Thinking about it again, `is_nan` could be calculated easier.

```
int is_nan(double x) { return !(x > DBL_MAX || x <= DBL_MAX); }
```

Or even without an included constant.

```
int is_nan(double x) { return !(x > 0.0 || x <= 0.0); }
```

Comment: `nan` does not compare equal, less than, or greater than to anything.

Comment: @S.S.Anne "nan does not compare equal, less than, or greater than to anything" is not specified by C89.   That is an IEEE 754 spec.  It's a good start, yet as OP wants a C89 solution, it is even more probable that  `nan` does not follow expected practices of today (2020).  OP may need a solution specific to the implementation.

Comment: Andreas, Minor: suggest `"% f"` --> `"% -14g"` for a cleaner informative table.

Comment: @S.S.Anne: In particular, for x is NaN (and only for NaN), `(x<C)==(x>=C)`  (both are false). This suggestion happens to use `C=FLT_MAX` for the constant to compare with, which is fine.  As for non-IEEE754 answers, that doesn't really make sense. NaN is very much an IEEE754 invention, and the non-signaling NaN in particular.