# Force C compilation error on simple arithmetic sanity check (addition, subtraction must match)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, assert, static-assert

### Context

Imagine some code correctness depends on some value adding or subtracting to some other, so that at compilation time one can know if compilation should be aborted.

For example :

```
some.h
#define A 100
#define B 20
#define C 120
```

Imagine that code in `some.c` assumes that `A+B == C`, else it does not even make sense to compile it.

### Wish

We wish compilation of `some.c` to fail if `A+B` is not equal to `C`.

```
some.cpp
#include "some.h"
#define CONTROL ((A)+(B)-(C))

something_that_cause_compilation_failure_if_argument_is_non_zero(CONTROL)
```

### Non-solutions

This does not work because preprocessor does not do arithmetic, only string substitution:

```
#if CONTROL
#else
#error MISMATCH
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

This is solved by static asserts and is standard since C11 as indicated by [Static assert in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385515/static-assert-in-c)

```
test.c

#define A 100
#define B 20
#define C 120

_Static_assert ( A+B == C, "A+B not equal to C");

int main()
{
    return 42;
}
```

```sh
gcc --std=c11 fail.c -o fail && echo SUCCESS

SUCCESS
```

If values are changed:

```sh
gcc --std=c11 fail.c -o fail

fail.c:14:1: error: static assertion failed: "A+B not equal to C"
   14 | _Static_assert ( A+B == C, "A+B not equal to C");
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```