# Is using assert() for production not favored over if..else.. blocks?

Tags: c, coding-style, if-statement, assert

I am finding that using `assert(...)` makes my code shorter and easier to read, as opposed to lengthy `if..else..` blocks. However, are there good *technical* reasons not to use `assert(...)` in shipping code, when it does the same thing as testing a `return` value while using less code?

Comment: Assertions catch programmer errors. Exceptions catch exceptional runtime errors. Conditionals guide normal program flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having read [this article](http://www.advogato.org/article/949.html) I will share my beliefs about `assert`:

1. Yes it's fine to use `assert` when something absolutely should meet the condition you are asserting.
2. Many languages allow you to raise custom errors when asserting, C not having "Exceptions" may produce errors that are a little harder to diagnose without directly looking at the source in question.

Comment: Okay, this is more along the direction I'm talking about, where an if-else block provides the opportunity to do more detailed error handling.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a **programming error** (possibly by the caller), use an `assert`.

If it's ***not*** a programming error, then use `if`/`else` and handle the situation appropriately.

Comment: Are there good *technical* reasons not to use assert, if it accomplishes the same effect as an if-else statement, while using less code?

Comment: @AlexReynolds: Nothing "technical" that I know of, if your goal is to bring the program crashing down. (If you want to catch the exception somewhere up, though, then it'd be hard to filter on the assertion rather than the exception.) But semantically it'd be lying to the reader. ;)

Comment: @AlexReynolds: `assert` is used to make your application crash in debug builds, this helps you find and fix situations/scenarios wherein your application just cannot work any further. *If-else* conditions are used to handle conditional situations.Ideally, our production code should not have any `assert`ing scenarios,assuming you weed such conditions out in debug versions already by making use of `assert`.

Answer (score 3):

Asserts are good. Compile-time asserts are even better. Note:

- BOOST has one, `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT()`.
- C++0x has `static_assert()`.
- And GCC since 4.3 has had a built-in `static_assert()`: [Does GCC have a built-in compile time assert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987684/does-gcc-have-a-built-in-compile-time-assert)
- C11 has `static_assert()` (`<assert.h>`).

If your environment doesn't already have a static assert, here is a suggestion.

The `ASSERT()` macro given below can be placed anywhere in the code, except:

- In a twice-included header file, without a `#ifndef...#endif` wrapper.
- In the middle of a structure definition (or enum definition).
- In strict C89 or C90, after a statement. (But you can wrap it in braces!)

If you want stick something in the middle of a structure definition you'll need to use the lengthy, ugly, three-line construct `#if...#error...#endif`. And if you do do this, the pre-processor has a *much* more limited idea of what a "constant expression" is.

This is a refinement of ideas from the web, primarily from http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html. This definition is shorter than `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT()`. And, I believe, is better than Linus's suggestion for an improved `BUILD_BUG_ON()`. And the `do{...}while(0)` wrapper you commonly see is totally inapplicable here, as it limits permissible locations.

This is also simpler than Google's COMPILE_ASSERT/CompileAssert. The 'sizeof bitfield' trick also seems good, from Linux's `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO()`, but *not* its useless sibling `BUILD_BUG_ON()`.

There are many suggestions for using arrays with a negative index. But with GCC, most of these do not detect a *non-constant* arg (which is easy enough to do in error), except for the 'extern int foo[expression]', which also gives an 'unused variable' warning. But `typedef int array[expression]` seems also to be good: see below.

The definition:

```
#define CONCAT_TOKENS(a, b)     a ## b
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_TOKENS(a, b)
#define ASSERT(e) enum{EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(ASSERT_line_,__LINE__) = 1/!!(e)}
```

Equally good, I believe, is the following variant, but it is longer by five characters:

```
#define ASSERT(e) typedef int EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(ASSERT_line_,__LINE__)[1-2*!(e)]
```

There is also the `do{switch(0){case 0:case(e):;}}while(0)` construct, which I haven't investigated.

Sometimes one needs a variant to handle the case where two different header files happen by chance to have two ASSERT()'s on the same line, or likewise for a source file and a header file. You could handle this via `__COUNTER__`, but this isn't supported by some compilers (and is uglier). And we can't use `__FILE__`, because it doesn't usually expand to a valid C token (e.g. it has a dot c or dot h). The Mozilla version http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mfbt/Assertions.h states that such conflicts "should be rare", but they'll greatly annoy your teammates when it happens. This can also be used to handle several `ASSERTS` in a multi-line macro, where `__LINE__` doesn't change.

```
#define ASSERTM(e,m) enum{EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(m##_ASSERT_line_,__LINE__)=1/!!(e)}
```

The next variant, `ASSERT_zero(),` is similar to `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(),` using the 'sizeof bitfield' trick. This yields either:

- a compile error, when `e` is false, or
- the value zero.

So it can be used in places where a statement cannot, such as in the middle of an expression.

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define ASSERT_zero(e) (!sizeof(struct{int:!!(e);})) // cf. BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(), !C++
#else
#define ASSERT_zero(e) (!sizeof(char[(e) ? 1 : -1])) // careful: g++ has VLAs
#endif
```

Comment: Regarding the last one (`ASSERT_zero`):  Why a different version for each language? Isn't there a version that works for both?  Does it work on g++?  If not, what could be used on g++?

Answer (score 3):

IMO none of the answers here says the most important part: Assert states programmers assumptions. `assert(x)` says something like *"x is always true at this point, you can check that if you want"*. If the user ever sees assertion error, it means you did something wrong.

What you probably need is a function which would do almost the same thing as assert, but both in release and debug modes. Using `check(x)` would mean *"Check that x is true. If it isn't, tell the user and quit"*

Answer (score 2):

`assert()` is designed for things that are never supposed to be false in sane circumstances.

`if`-`else` is designed for things that may sometimes be false in sane circumstances, because the `else` portion is designed for handle such situations gracefully.

**In short, `if` statements are designed to *avoid* crashes; `assert()` is designed to *cause* them.**

Comment: I guess I should clarify. What are the *technical* reasons not to use assert, when it accomplishes the same end as an if-else statement?

Comment: That's just it... it doesn't. There's no `else` for an assert; if the assertion fails, you can't specify what happens. Hence why `assert()` is only for things that *shouldn't* fail, ever. `if-else` is designed to avoid crashes; `assert()` is designed to *cause* crashes.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers have some good information, none seems (to me) to have directly addressed the question you asked.

IMO, yes, there's a fairly significant shortcoming to leaving `assert`s in (most) production code: you get no control over the error message it displays, which is often rather scary looking.

Instead of something like:

```
Fatal error: Assertion failed! x != NULL in xxx.c, line 107
```

I'd rather give the customer something like:

```
Please contact customer support and give them code xxx:107
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using `assert` for runtime errors is poor form, particularly because it defies convention:

- `assert` typically is compiled out of non-debug builds.  Now, *you* might choose to compile all your builds with the expectation that `assert` is always enabled, but anyone who inherits your code later might not understand that.  It'll be even worse if you write code where your `assert`s have side-effects (such as `assert((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL)`).
- Similarly, `assert` is intended to be used for logical errors, not runtime errors.  When you start using `assert` to check runtime errors, you start misrepresenting how your code is supposed to behave to anyone who tries to read it.  Maintainers will not be able to distinguish easily between logical errors and potential runtime errors, and the distinction is useful when reasoning about code behavior.

And do you really want your program to terminate abruptly and dump core if a user accidentally leaves some input field blank?  That's incredibly user-hostile.

If you feel that using `assert` is less code, then you could try writing your own, separate macro.  That would avoid changing the expected semantics of `assert` and the hostility.  For example, something like:

```
#define FAIL_IF(cond, action) do { if (cond) { action; } } while (0)

FAIL_IF((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL, goto exit);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't share the point of those who say it's valid. Once I've got screwed by the fact that Qt's asserts were defined like as follows:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#  define q_assert(...) ...
#endif
```

and I used to write something like

```
q_assert(some_ptr_type a = get_new_ptr());
```

When I've complied it in release mode, I was quite puzzled by `a` never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Like java Exceptions `assert` gives a *fail-fast*. That is a very good practice saving much development time and effort. But the shipping code should have fast releases as a web application, and not something like a CD distro. Furthermore in java exceptions may be intercepted, logged and nicely presented.

Comment: Accepted. Was just comparing C with maybe the most dominant high-level platform. Fail-fast is undervaluated in our C world. You picked the right answer anyway.