# Force function to accept specific definitions only?

Tags: c

I would like to force a functions parameters to accept only specific definitions. For example, consider `#define OUTPUT 1`, `#define INPUT 0` and `void restrictedFunction(int parameter);` .

How would I force `restrictedFunction(int parameter)` to accept only `OUTPUT` or `INPUT`?

I would also like to take into consideration that another definition may have the same value, for example, `#define LEFT 1` and `#define RIGHT 0`.

So in this case I would like `restrictedFunction(int parameter)` to be able to accept only `OUTPUT` and `INPUT` specifically.

Comment: Not possible with `#define`s, the compiler-proper doesn't see them, it only sees the replaced values.

Comment: named enums? can you do it with that? i feel like you can with C++, but not sure how strong they are in C

Comment: Is there any other method that would do this?

Comment: You can't force it to receive a specific value, even if you were in C++ and used `enum`s (since `enum` is just an `int`). You'd better check inside the function for the parameter value and report an error if it is out ot allowed range (You can use `assert`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef enum { INPUT = 0, OUTPUT = 1 } IO_Type;

void restrictedFunction(IO_Type parameter) { ... }
```

It doesn't absolutely force the use of the values (the compiler will let someone write `restrictedFunction(4)`), but it is about as good as you'll get.

If you truly want to force the correct type, then:

```
typedef enum { INPUT = 0, OUTPUT = 1 } IO_Type;
typedef struct { IO_Type io_type } IO_Param;

void restrictedFunction(IO_Param parameter) { ... }
```

In C99 or later, you could call that with:

```
restrictedFunction((IO_Param){ INPUT });
```

This is a compound literal, creating a structure on the fly.  It is not entirely clear that the structure type really buys you very much, but it will force the users to think a little and may improve the diagnostics from the compiler when they use it wrong (but they can probably use `restrictedFunction((IO_Param){ 4 });` still).

What this means is that your `restrictedFunction()` code should be ready to validate the argument:

```
void restrictedFunction(IO_Type io_type)
{
    switch (io_type)
    {
    case INPUT:
        ...do input handling...
        break;
    case OUTPUT:
        ...do output handling...
        break;
    default:
        assert(io_type != INPUT && io_type != OUTPUT);
        ...or other error handling...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The latter suggestion doesn't really improve anything -- someone could still call it with `(struct IO_Param){ 4 }`.

Comment: I can still do this: `IO_Param m; m.io_type = 40;` :P

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Agreed; I added the content of your comment to my answer (of my own volition) at about the same time that you added your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum.

```
typedef enum TrafficDirection { INPUT = 0, OUTPUT = 1 } TrafficDirection;

restrictedFunction(TrafficDirection direction);
```

of course, this isn't perfect.  You can still pass any int to it as long as you use a cast.

```
restrictedFunction((TrafficDirection) 4);
```

Comment: It would be wise to note that this is only en effort to hint users of the function, but not a way of restricting them from passing something else if they really want to.

Comment: You mean kind of like I already did?  "You can still pass any int to it as long as you use a cast."

Answer (score 1):

You don't get quite as much protection as you might like, but you can do:

```
enum func_type { INPUT, OUTPUT };
void restrictedFunction( enum func_type parameter );
```

Comment: I can still do this: `restrictedFunction(50);` :P

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper to validate the argument:

```
#define restrictedFunction(x) do {                          \
   static_assert((x) == INPUT || (x) == OUTPUT);            \
   assert(!strcmp(#x, "INPUT") || !strcmp(#x, "OUTPUT"));   \
   restrictedFunction(x);                                   \
} while(0)
```

Notes:

- This assumes `restrictedFunction()` returns a `void.` If it returns a value which you actually use, you'll need something like gcc's compound statement http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html. Or--better--you can use `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO` (see [What is ":-!!" in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9229601/318716)), which I keep forgetting about, because it doesn't seem to work with C++.
- The `do ... while(0)` is to "swallow the semi-colon"; not really relevant here.
- `static_assert()` is a compile-time assert; there are many variants available. Here is a link to one, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059896/318716, if you don't have your own handy.
- `assert()` is the standard run-time assert.
- With gcc 4.1.2, and my version of `static_assert(),` you can replace the run-time `assert()` with a compile-time assert when the two `!strcmp()`'s are replaced with `==`; see example below.  I haven't tested this with other compilers.
- `x` is only used ***once*** in the macro expansion, since the first four references are only used at compile-time.

When your actually define your function, you'll have to add parentheses to disable the macro expansion, as in:

```
void (restrictedFunction)(int x){ ... }
```

Also, if your code has a special case (whose code doesn't?) where you need to call `restrictedFunction()` with the argument `foo,` you'll need to write:

```
  (restrictedFunction)(foo);
```

Here is a complete example, which puts a wrapper around the standard library function `exit()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONCAT_TOKENS(a, b)     a ## b
#define EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(a,b) CONCAT_TOKENS(a, b)
#define ASSERT(e)    enum{EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(ASSERT_line_,__LINE__) = 1/!!(e)}
#define ASSERTM(e,m) enum{EXPAND_THEN_CONCAT(m##_ASSERT_line_,__LINE__)=1/!!(e)}

#define exit(x) do {                                                \
   ASSERTM((x) ==  EXIT_SUCCESS  || (x) ==  EXIT_FAILURE,  value);  \
   ASSERTM(#x  == "EXIT_SUCCESS" || #x  == "EXIT_FAILURE", symbol); \
   exit(x);                                                         \
} while(0)

int main(void) {
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // good
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // good
   exit(0);  // bad
   exit(3);  // doubly bad
}
```

If I try to compile it, I get:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo
foo.c: In function 'main':
foo.c:17: error: enumerator value for 'symbol_ASSERT_line_17' is not an integer constant
foo.c:18: warning: division by zero
foo.c:18: error: enumerator value for 'value_ASSERT_line_18' is not an integer constant
foo.c:18: error: enumerator value for 'symbol_ASSERT_line_18' is not an integer constant
```